# taskkill command only killing the file explorer opened using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: windows-explorer, python, task-manager, wmi

I have opened two instances of `D:\akshit` folder. One I opened manually using GUI. But the other one, I created with a script that calls `subprocess.Popen()`. Now whenever I write the following command, only the instance opened using `subprocess.Popen()` is being killed:

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq akshit" /IM explorer.exe
```

Can anyone explain on what basis does the `taskkill` decide to not kill the other instances? Can I somehow change this behavior to kill all the instances with the window title "akshit"?

Comment: What happens if you use `TASKLIST /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq akshit" /IM explorer.exe`? this command is to list the tasks. If it also only shows one result, then you have your answer. You can use TASKLIST to figure out what to change in order to make TASKKILL behave properly.

Comment: we cant use /F or /IM with tasklist.
It gives invalid argument.

Answer (score 1):

It is not TaskKill's fault. While you have opened two File Explorer windows, this does not necessarily mean that you have opened two separate processes for each.

One of the settings that can impact your situation can be found under:

Folder Options → View tab → Advanced settings → "Launch folder windows in a separate process"

This setting has the following effects:

- If this checkbox *is not* checked, most of the times, File Explorer windows are opened in the same `explorer.exe` process that hosts task bar and Start menu. This process's window title is fixed. If you kill this process, you entire Windows shell disappears.
- If this checkbox *is* checked, the process that hosts task bar and Start menu is always separate from the process hosting your File Explorer windows. But still, **this does not mean that you get one separate `explorer.exe` process for each File Explorer window.** I tested this in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 10 1709. I always get exactly one `explorer.exe` process for all my File Explorer windows and one other `explorer.exe` for my taskbar and Start menu. The `WINDOWTITLE` of that process is always the title of the File Explorer window that was open last.

One reason that `subprocess.Popen()` opens a separate File Explorer process could be that you are running a 32-bit Python on a 64-bit computer, in which case, `subprocess.Popen()` just opens a 32-bit `explorer.exe`. (This does not happen in all versions of Windows, but again, you didn't specify any.) Another reason is out-of-process DCOM invocation that always trips me up.

But the gist of it is:

- Window ≠ Process

Comment: Thanks!!
It is working fine now.
Is it possible to control set this option via python script?

Comment: It is possible, but it won't take effect until the computer is restarted. It is a setting in Windows Registry. I am not sure exactly where, but you can probably use Sysinternals Process Monitor to find it, if a Google search didn't gave you the answer.